# Why do I have 2 instances of SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm new to SQL Server and I'm trying to learn MVC for some school projects. I have a program that creates a DB with Code-first approach in Entity framework. But when I tried to find it in my SQL Server Management Studio I didn't find it. So I checked in Visual Studio 2013 "SQL Server Object Explorer" and find that I have 2 SQL Server instances. Since I'm only writing to one SQL Server instance I decided to delete the one at the top. But as soon as I restart my program it's there again. How can I only have 1 instance to write to ? The DB I'm writing to is the one at the bottom "TestDB". [image]

**Edit**
Adding DB Context by request
[image]

Comment: Could you please share with us code with initializing of Context?

Comment: @KamilStachowiak The Webconfig or The class or Both?

Comment: cs where initialized Context. Im interested in, If there is named connection string or not

Comment: @KamilStachowiak I put up a picture of my Class. And here is my connection string`

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; User Id=Seeya; Password=;Initial Catalog=CodeFirstTest; Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: You are not using this connection string now, because it's not given in parameter. You should call base method constructor in your class like this:

:base("UserContext") Because otherwise by default is used Default db engine, so local db (files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your code currently `EF` not use at all `ConnectionString` you expecting.

This is how this should look like:

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="UserContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; User Id=Seeya; Password=;Initial Catalog=CodeFirstTest; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

and now Your Context:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
     public UserContext() 
     :base("UserContext")
     {
     }
  //REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

The other instance is because EF craeted [SQLCompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact), when nothing was given as parameter to base method of Context.

Comment: Okey That explains why it adds a new DB called "UserContext_CodeFirst_EF" But why do I have 2 instances of SQL Server and why does it keep coming back after I delete it?

Comment: probably after application run? SQLCompact is db stored in file. I belive, when you initialize your context, it just generates file in SQLCompact for you. When you are using VS it maintian information about servers from solution + local real SQL instance. This is reason why you see more instances.

Comment: Thanks! I will look intot this and hopefully get an understanding. If you have some links I can read and look up, to get a better understanding to this WHOLE SQL Server stuff (Reading for beginners like me), I would appreciate it ALOT.